# jquery iterate through dynamic complex object submit to asp.net mvc action

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to iterate through a complex type binding in jQuery to submit the Json representation through to an IEnumerable action parameter.

**Html**

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="value.index" />
<input type="text" value="textone" name="value[0].InputValue" id="value[0].InputValue" />
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="value[0].Id" id="value[0].Id" />
```

**jQuery**

```
var value = $('#value[0].InputValue').val()
```

The value returned is undefined; however if I have a control with an id in the format of "myId" then I can access the value of that control.

Am I missing something? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` is used to find the element by Id. If you want to find the element by Name, it follows a different syntax... Try this

```
$("input[name=value\[0\].InputValue]");
```

Comment: Ta muchly, this was what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think []'s are allowed in IDs.  MVC replaces them with underscores when I render a textbox with a name of `Obj[0].Property`

I'd try getting the input by the name:

**EDIT - escape the brackets :)**

```
$('input[name=value\[0\].InputValue]').val()
```

You can do a variety of attribute selectors too:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises because the [ and ] characters mean special things in a jQuery selector, namely they specify requirements on attributes. so when you say

```
$('#value[0].InputValue')
```

that means to jQuery "element with **id of "value"** and **the attribute "0" present** and with the **css class InputValue applied**.

As others have suggested, use $('input[name=value[0].InputValue')` instead.